# Greenplum database binary package

Tags: greenplum

I know this is awkward but I can't find the binary package to install Greenplum database on my Centos machine in order to create a cluster of 4 nodes to test this database, 
[this tutorial](http://www.zhongweicheng.com/?p=3470)

considers I have the `greenplum-db-5.4.0-rhel7-x86_64.bin` package which I don't have,
following the `README` from the `greenplum-db` Github repo [gpdb repo](https://github.com/greenplum-db/gpdb)

fails also due to some error also:

> ,"could not create semaphores: No space left on device (pg_sema.c:127)","Failed system call was semget(118, 17, 03600).","This error does *not* mean that you have run out of disk space.

I can't seem to setup a successful `greenplum` cluster
any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any RHEL package from:
https://network.pivotal.io/products/pivotal-gpdb#/releases

Current version is 5.9.0. but 5.4.0 is available as a bin or rpm.

You can also build and use the community edition on GIT.

The semaphores error is due to the OS limits, which need to be modified before installation.

See: https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/590/install_guide/prep_os_install_gpdb.html#topic3

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I tried to download RHEL package from the link you provided, under the `Greenplum Database Server` folder but for some reason it gives me the following error : > Unable to Download
Unfortunately, we are unable to provide you with access to download software at this time. Please contact export@pivotal.io for assistance.

Comment: I tried a different account and it works, thank you, but the idea is that I was aiming to download the community version meaning I didn't want the pivotal Greenplum database

Comment: You can find a number of download options here: https://greenplum.org/download/ - if that does not help, you might have to build from source.

Answer (score 1):

To help clarify, if you are looking for a binary installer (.bin) of Greenplum, those are only found on the Pivotal Network download site, as Brendan points out.

Currently, binary installers are not provided on the greenplum.org site, so you will need to build Greenplum Database from source.

Comment: thank you, but what's the difference here? pivotal Greenplum is the commercial version? meaning it's not free? and greenplum from greenplum.org is the free one?

Comment: That's correct -- 
The greenplum binaries from Pivotal Network are licensed products and pre-compiled.
The greenplum community edition is open source and you will need to build it.